# How to find the first row with a different value within a column for a pandas df?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, like so:

| Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2020/01/01 | 1 |
| 2020/01/02 | 1 |
| 2020/01/03 | 2 |
| 2020/01/04 | 2 |
| 2020/01/05 | 1 |
| 2020/01/06 | 1 |

I'd like the first date for each new value within the "Quantity" column, like so:

| Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2020/01/01 | 1 |
| 2020/01/03 | 2 |
| 2020/01/05 | 1 |

The values within "Quantity" can repeat so dropping duplicates is not a solution for me.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to keep the first row and every row in which the quantity changes, right? So you can do

```py
q = df['Quantity'].values
sel = np.r_[True, q[1:] != q[:-1]]
df = df.loc[sel, :]
```

where I've called df your DataFrame. What this is doing is simply comparing if the n-th element starting from 1 (i.e the second element) is different from the (n-1)-th, and selecting if so.

Answer (score 0):

About the same as @BVJ but use only pandas to do the job:

```
>>> df.loc[(df - df.shift(1) != 0).values]
            value
date
2020-01-01      1
2020-01-03      2
2020-01-05      1
```

```
>>> df
            value
date
2020-01-01      1
2020-01-03      2
2020-01-05      1

>> df.shift(1)
            value
date
2020-01-01    NaN
2020-01-02    1.0
2020-01-03    1.0
2020-01-04    2.0
2020-01-05    2.0
2020-01-06    1.0

>>> df - df.shift(1)
            value
date
2020-01-01    NaN
2020-01-02    0.0  # value is the same as previous, don't want to keep it
2020-01-03    1.0
2020-01-04    0.0  # value is the same as previous, don't want to keep it
2020-01-05   -1.0
2020-01-06    0.0  # value is the same as previous, don't want to keep it

>>> df - df.shift(1) != 0
            value
date
2020-01-01   True
2020-01-02  False
2020-01-03   True
2020-01-04  False
2020-01-05   True
2020-01-06  False
```